# Multiple HttpResponse with multi threading in controller result in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have a list of PDF files and user wants to choose multiple files and donwload them simultaneously in one Action method.

Is it possible to create multiple thread and each thread returns pdf file in response.

Comment: The browser expects one response only, so I don't think this can be done. You can zip all the files and send the zip file.

Comment: its not possible to return multiple object in response

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class with a list of PDFs

When your user selects multiple files you populate your class's list.

Add to the class a method to push one file to client and another to loop through the list pushing files to client.

From your controller call the loop method.